# How to implent a "maketrans" python function on field calculator

Tags: python, field-calculator

i'm traying to implent python string translate function at field calculatore
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm
in order to fix hebrew imported from cad. here is the code -

```
def Ttxt (RefName):
  from string import maketrans   
  intab = "asdfghjkl"
  outtab = "שדגכעיחלך"
  return trantab = maketrans(intab, outtab)

Ttxt( !RefName! )
```

Any sugestion about how to right this function ?

Comment: What kind of software do you use? It is not obvious from question what is field calculator.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the examples on the site you would need something like this (untested):

```
def Ttxt (RefName):
  from string import maketrans   
  intab = "שדגכעיחלך"
  outtab = "asdfghjkl"
  trantab = maketrans(intab, outtab)

  return RefName.translate(trantab)
```

Comment: now i get this error messege:  000539 'return' outside function (<string>, line 6)

Comment: You haven't got your function formatted correctly

Comment: def Ttxt (RefName):
  import string
  from string import maketrans   
   intab = "asdfghjkl"
   outtab = "שדגכעיחלך"
  transtab = string.maketrans(intab, outtab)
  return RefName.translate(transtab)
and now 000989 unexspected indent (line 4)

Comment: posting Python in the comments isn't going to help because Python uses white space to work out code blocks.  Maybe read up on a bit of Python first.